# Import multiple RTF files' data into separate worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, rtf

I'm new in Excel VBA.

I have multiple rich text format files (.rtf) in a folder. I want the .rtf files opened in Excel and each file represented by one worksheet

```
Sub Try()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim FSO         As New FileSystemObject
    Dim Fldr        As Folder
    Dim Fl          As file
    Dim WkSht       As Worksheet
    Dim StrName     As String
    Dim WkBk_Tmp    As Workbook
    Dim WkSht_Tmp   As Worksheet

    Set Fldr = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\NHWD78\Desktop\Report\Harmonic and Flicker") 'folder path
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")  'run in word application

    For Each Fl In Fldr.Files   'loop to search for rft files
        If Right(UCase(Fl.Name), 4) = ".RTF" Then

            StrName = Left(Fl.Name, Len(Fl.Name) - 4)
            Set WkSht = Worksheets.Add  'add worksheet
            WkSht.Name = StrName    'worksheet name equals to file name

            With WordApp    'open file and copy content
                .Documents.Open FileName:=(Fl.Path)
                .ActiveDocument.Select
                .Selection.Copy

                ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select 'paste content
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                WordApp.Quit

                Columns.AutoFit
                Set WordApp = Nothing

            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I tried to modify the code but it only copies the first file in the folder and is unable to loop the other files.